Why isn't the following text being collapsed into a ellipsis?
This is the code:
<div class="grid w-full gap-4 grid-cols-8">
  <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 justify-center items-center max-w-small cursor-not-allowed"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-file-filled h-10 w-10">
      <path d="M12 2l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v4l.005 .15a2 2 0 0 0 1.838 1.844l.157 .006h4l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v9a3 3 0 0 1 -2.824 2.995l-.176 .005h-10a3 3 0 0 1 -2.995 -2.824l-.005 -.176v-14a3 3 0 0 1 2.824 -2.995l.176 -.005h5z"></path>
      <path d="M19 7h-4l-.001 -4.001z"></path>
    </svg><span class="overflow-hidden text-ellipsis text-center text-xs">sssssssssssssss</span></div>
  <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 justify-center items-center max-w-small cursor-not-allowed"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-file-filled h-10 w-10">
      <path d="M12 2l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v4l.005 .15a2 2 0 0 0 1.838 1.844l.157 .006h4l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v9a3 3 0 0 1 -2.824 2.995l-.176 .005h-10a3 3 0 0 1 -2.995 -2.824l-.005 -.176v-14a3 3 0 0 1 2.824 -2.995l.176 -.005h5z"></path>
      <path d="M19 7h-4l-.001 -4.001z"></path>
    </svg><span class="overflow-hidden text-ellipsis text-center text-xs">dummy.mib</span></div>
</div>

The text breaks out of the container instead of being collapsed. Why is that, and how to fix it?
Tailwind Play


The text breaks out of the container

This is because sssssss...  is a continuous word and does not force a line break by default. In Tailwind you can use break-all to make text break at any position.
And it seems you intend to implement text overflow ellipsis. In Tailwind you can just use line-clamp-* to achieve this effect directly.
<div class="grid w-full grid-cols-8 gap-4">
  <div class="max-w-small flex w-full cursor-not-allowed flex-col items-center justify-center gap-1">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-file-filled h-10 w-10">
      <path d="M12 2l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v4l.005 .15a2 2 0 0 0 1.838 1.844l.157 .006h4l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v9a3 3 0 0 1 -2.824 2.995l-.176 .005h-10a3 3 0 0 1 -2.995 -2.824l-.005 -.176v-14a3 3 0 0 1 2.824 -2.995l.176 -.005h5z"></path>
      <path d="M19 7h-4l-.001 -4.001z"></path></svg
    ><span class="line-clamp-2 break-all text-center text-xs">ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</span>
  </div>
  <div class="max-w-small flex w-full cursor-not-allowed flex-col items-center justify-center gap-1">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-file-filled h-10 w-10">
      <path d="M12 2l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v4l.005 .15a2 2 0 0 0 1.838 1.844l.157 .006h4l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v9a3 3 0 0 1 -2.824 2.995l-.176 .005h-10a3 3 0 0 1 -2.995 -2.824l-.005 -.176v-14a3 3 0 0 1 2.824 -2.995l.176 -.005h5z"></path>
      <path d="M19 7h-4l-.001 -4.001z"></path></svg
    ><span class="line-clamp-2 break-all text-center text-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, praesentium.</span>
  </div>
</div>

DEMO on Tailwind Play.

the easy thing I did was to change the overflow to the top div.
<div class="grid w-full gap-4 grid-cols-8">
  <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 justify-center overflow-hidden items-center max-w-small cursor-not-allowed"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-file-filled h-10 w-10">
      <path d="M12 2l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v4l.005 .15a2 2 0 0 0 1.838 1.844l.157 .006h4l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v9a3 3 0 0 1 -2.824 2.995l-.176 .005h-10a3 3 0 0 1 -2.995 -2.824l-.005 -.176v-14a3 3 0 0 1 2.824 -2.995l.176 -.005h5z"></path>
      <path d="M19 7h-4l-.001 -4.001z"></path>
    </svg>
    <span class="text-ellipsis text-center text-xs">sssssssssssssssssssssssssssadasd</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 justify-center overflow-hidden items-center max-w-small cursor-not-allowed"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-file-filled h-10 w-10">
      <path d="M12 2l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v4l.005 .15a2 2 0 0 0 1.838 1.844l.157 .006h4l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v9a3 3 0 0 1 -2.824 2.995l-.176 .005h-10a3 3 0 0 1 -2.995 -2.824l-.005 -.176v-14a3 3 0 0 1 2.824 -2.995l.176 -.005h5z"></path>
      <path d="M19 7h-4l-.001 -4.001z"></path>
    </svg><span class="text-ellipsis text-center text-xs">dummy.mibasdasdasdsad</span></div>
</div>


try this code


<div class="grid w-full gap-4 grid-cols-8">
  <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 justify-center items-center max-w-small cursor-not-allowed" style="width: 100px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-file-filled h-10 w-10">
      <path d="M12 2l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v4l.005 .15a2 2 0 0 0 1.838 1.844l.157 .006h4l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v9a3 3 0 0 1 -2.824 2.995l-.176 .005h-10a3 3 0 0 1 -2.995 -2.824l-.005 -.176v-14a3 3 0 0 1 2.824 -2.995l.176 -.005h5z"></path>
      <path d="M19 7h-4l-.001 -4.001z"></path>
    </svg>
    <span class="overflow-hidden text-ellipsis text-center text-xs" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 100%;">sssssssssssssss</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 justify-center items-center max-w-small cursor-not-allowed" style="width: 100px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-file-filled h-10 w-10">
      <path d="M12 2l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v4l.005 .15a2 2 0 0 0 1.838 1.844l.157 .006h4l.117 .007a1 1 0 0 1 .876 .876l.007 .117v9a3 3 0 0 1 -2.824 2.995l-.176 .005h-10a3 3 0 0 1 -2.995 -2.824l-.005 -.176v-14a3 3 0 0 1 2.824 -2.995l.176 -.005h5z"></path>
      <path d="M19 7h-4l-.001 -4.001z"></path>
    </svg>
    <span class="overflow-hidden text-ellipsis text-center text-xs" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 100%;">dummy.mib</span>
  </div>
</div>




Sorry, could you use TailwindCSS instead?
